# GooglePlay - Closed/Internal Testing: How to remove/disable App on Tester's Device?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have GooglePlay Internal and Closed Alpha Testing setup for my Android app.

It works great for allowing testers to join the program and install the app BUT when I remove the Tester from the Tester email list, they can still use the app.

Is there any way to de-activate the installed version or even the build from the Developer Console (https://play.google.com/console/u/0/developers/) or is this even possible?
(I'm basically looking for similar functionality that Apple's AppStoreConnect/TestFlight gives us on iOS).

Thanks in advance!

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, unfortunately.

As of 29 Oct 2020 all you can do is remove testers from the closed test track and that prevents them from getting further updates.

Comment: Thanks!! I think we will have to do it programatically so from within the app.